# Is there an efficient way in docpad to keep static and to-be-rendered files in the same directory?

Tags: docpad

I am rebuilding a site with docpad and it's very liberating to form a folders structure that makes sense with my workflow of content-creation, but I'm running into a problem with docpad's hard-division of content-to-be-rendered vs 'static'-content.

Docpad recommends that you put things like images in /files instead of /documents, and the documentation makes it sound as if otherwise there will be some processing overhead incurred.

- First, I'd like an explanation if anyone has it of why a file with a
  single extension (therefore no rendering) and no YAML front-matter,
  such as a .jpg, would impact site-regeneration time when placed
  within /documents.
- Second, the real issue: is there a way, if it does indeed create a
  performance hit, to mitigate it? For example, to specify an 'ignore'
  list with regex, etc...

#### My use case

I would like to do this for posts and their associated images to make authoring a post more natural. I can easily see the images I have to work with and all the related files are in one place.

I also am doing this for an artwork I am displaying. In this case it's an even stronger use case, as the only data in my html.eco file is yaml front matter of various meta data, my layout automatically generates the gallery from all the attached images located in a folder of the same-name as the post. I can match the relative output path folder in my /files directory but it's error prone, because you're in one folder (src/files/artworks/) when creating the folder of images and another (src/documents/artworks/) when creating the html file -- typos are far more likely (as you can't ever see the folder and the html file side by side)...

**Even without justifying a use case** I can't see why docpad should be putting forth such a hard division. A performance consideration should not be passed on to the end user like that if it can be avoided in any way; since with docpad I am likely to be managing my blog through the file system I ought to have full control over that structure and certainly don't want my content divided up based on some framework limitation or performance concern instead of based on logical content divisions.

Comment: I did locate in the configuration file a way to selectively ignore certain directories from *scanning* but I do not believe this is the essential difference between ```files/``` and ```documents/``` as files placed with ```files/``` and then renamed still seem to trigger a re-build. But for anyone looking for a way to selectively avoid scanning certain directories it you can specify ```ignorePaths:``` in the configuration file which "Can be set to an array of absolute paths that we should ignore from the scanning process."

Comment: According to docpad documentation files within the ```files/``` path "are not rendered and do not support meta data. This is where you should put everything that doesn't need to be rendered or need meta data. For example, images, vendor files, plain stylesheet and JavaScript files etc." 

This is confusing, because rendering is only going to happen with items with two extensions, so there is already control over that at the file level, and the examples cited of images already cannot support YAML front matter. Still not sure what possible advantage putting jpgs in ```files/``` could give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key is the line about "metadata".Even though a file does NOT have a double extension, it can still have metadata at the top of the file which needs to be scanned and read. The double extension really just tells docpad to convert the file from one format and output it as another. If I create a straight html file in the document folder I can still include the metadata header in the form:

```
---
tags: ['tag1','tag2','tag3']
title: 'Some title'
---
```

When the file is copied to the out directory, this metadata will be removed. If I do the same thing to a html file in the files directory, the file will be copied to the out directory with the metadata header intact. So, the answer to your question is that even though your file has a single extension and is not "rendered" as such, it still needs to be opened and processed.

The point you make, however, is a good one. Keeping images and documents together. I can see a good argument for excluding certain file extensions (like image files) from being processed. Or perhaps, only including certain file extensions.

Comment: This is  mostly my understanding of it as well, but one thing is not entirely clear from your explanation. Are you saying that Docpad currently opens each file in ```documents``` and checks for the YAML metadata *even if the file extension indicates that it is a binary file (i.e. ```jpg```)?* Do you have any idea of the significance of the performance hit one is likely to get for Docpad to process a file when there is no YAML metadata in it? I am guessing it is quite negligible (especially considering it will only happen when the file is modified or first created?)

Comment: @birchbark Yes, I'm saying that I "believe" that Docapad opens each file in the documents directory. I can't say for sure as I haven't done any in-depth investigation. But the example with the plain html file has me believing. I think the performance hit is significant - which is why I said you had a good point.