# Having assets in post folder in Docpad

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, docpad

When using Docpad, I would like to be able to keep images, stylesheets and scripts for a certain post in that post's folder:

```
documents
    posts
        post1
            index.html.eco
            style.css
            main.js
            myimage.jpg
```

But their include paths inside the index.html.eco gets messed up

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

resolves to:

```
<script src="posts/main.js"></script>
```

The docpad.coffee defines the collection as such:

```
posts: (database) ->
    database.findAllLive({
        layout:$has:'post'
        relativeOutDirPath: /posts[\/\\]\w+/
    }, [date:-1] )
```

And even if I change the path manually to be correct, the preview server can't seem to find the asset (none of them), even though they have been copied to the out/-folder. Also, it goes into an infinite re-rendering loop (it does not matter if I use findAll or findAllLive) which crashes the page.

I've tried searching the documentation and SO and alike for anybody who have wanted to do something similar but can only seem  to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850539/is-there-an-efficient-way-in-docpad-to-keep-static-and-to-be-rendered-files-in-t). However I don't feel it answers my question, only does discussion on the subject.

Is this simply not possible or am I missing something?